# Separate tiles for different Outlook Inboxes

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-920, tiles, pin-to-start

I have a Nokia Lumia 920 running Windows 10. I also have more than one Gmail account. I used to have separate tiles for two separate Gmail accounts on the start screen. One of them disappeared. I have reinstated an Outlook mail tile by linking my outlook.com account to one of the Gmail accounts, but how can I pin the other one to the start screen? Long pressing the account name in the "manage accounts" screen does not bring up Pin to Start and the phone will not pin to start more than once for Outlook mail. Help, please.

Answer (score 1):

The place to pin different accounts to Start is in the account switcher, not in the Settings -> "Manage accounts" view.

I also have multiple Google accounts (Gmail+Calendar, etc.). These are the instructions from my Lumia 950 XL running the latest W10M Insider in portrait orientation; it's vaguely possible they may be slightly different on the 920 due to older version and/or lower resolution:

1. Go to the Store and make sure your "Mail and Calendar" app is up to date. It's unlikely to be that outdated - they haven't made any major changes to the mobile version in probably over a year - but worth checking anyhow.
2. Launch Mail (to any inbox; it doesn't matter which one), either from a Start tile or using "Outlook Mail" in the Start app list.
3. In the upper left, just under the phone's status bar/system tray and to the left of the account name, there's a "hamburger menu" button (three short horizontal lines, tightly spaced). Tap it.
4. The screen that appears should list all of your configured accounts on the device (under an "Accounts") heading, and also all of your folders for the current account (under a "Folders" heading); the current account and folder will be highlighted. *Incidentally, you can use this view to switch accounts and folders without going back to Start.*
5. Press-and-hold on any account (or folder!) and a context menu will appear with a "Pin to Start" option (or "Unpin from Start", for things that are already pinned).
6. Pin anything that you want to, and then you can manipulate the tiles on the Start screen as usual (resize them, stack them into folders, unpin them, etc.).